# UseLazyQuery not being called inside another hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, apollo

I have a place where I call 2 queries in multiple places. So I thought I'd make a custom hook to call both queries together. the first is a query, the second a lazy query on button click.

```
const useMyHook = () => {
  const {data} = useMyCustomQuery()

  const [getFunction] = useMyCustomLazyQuery()

 return { data, getFunction }
}
```

When I run this (simplified) code, it looks like in the network tab the first query runs fine but then get I try to call `getFunction` on a button click, nothing happens? is this possible and if so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you actually get any data from your useMyCustomLazyQuery? you can return data by deconstructing the lazyQuery [getFunction, {data, loading, error}]

Comment: can you please post code snippet for button click